# Multi-objective nonlinear programming

Tags: mathematical-optimization

How to use mathematica to solve multi-objective nonlinear programming.
These are two objective functions:

\begin{array}{l}
M{\rm{ = }}{{\rm{C}}_1}{\rm{ - }}\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{15} {\sum\limits_{j = 1}^2 {\frac{{{{\rm{C}}_2}}}{{{t_{ij}}}}} } \\
K{\rm{ = }}\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{15} {\sum\limits_{j = 1}^2 {{C_3}\frac{1}{{{t_{ij}}}}} } 
\end{array}
C1 and C3 are constants.

And some restrictions. Is there any method or function that can be solved?
The Maximize function can only find the maximum value of one function. I need to find the maximum value of both functions at the same time.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If so, please show it! What would the inputs/outputs be if a function is defined?

Comment: I have no ideas. I want to know how to use mathematica to solve similar problems.

Comment: @Mertin There are no methods in Mathematica to do this out of the box, but that doesn't mean we couldn't make one from NMinimize/NMaximize. There's not enough information in your question to answer meaningfully. Are you trying to minimize or maximize $M$ and $K$ ? Do you know if it's possible to turn the problem into a single objective minimization? What are the constraints/restrictions you mention? And what is the domain for the $t_{ij}$ ?

Comment: The Maximize function can only find the maximum value of one function. I need to find the maximum value of both functions at the same time.

Comment: See "Multiobjective Optimization: Goal Programming" in http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationLocalNumerical.html to this end.